# Value entered into prompt box needs to insert into a algorithm to display a certain number of variations of the user entered title

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

The user will enter a title in the prompt box and from there it should load the function generate_title() and from there it should display the result on the page to be different variations of the title that the user entered. However it will not display the title on the page with the variations. I need help. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdaxs2e6/) document.

HTML code is below:

```
<body>

<h1>Title Generation Module</h1>

<script>
     pTitle = prompt("Enter a title", "Enter your title");
    if (pTitle == null || pTitle == " ")
    {
        alert("Not a vaild Title");
    }
    else
    {
        var r = confirm("Are you wanting to submit this title: "+pTitle);
        if (r == true)
        {
            //document.write(pTitle);
           generate_title();
        }
        else
        {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Javascript is as follows:

```
//Generate Title


var input_keywords = pTitle;
    var limit_count = 1;
    var max_char_per_title = 80;
    var sub_library = ["for=4", "you=u", "at=@", "two=2", "with=w", "adapter=adpt", "Monokini=Mono 9"].map( function (item)
        { return item.split("=");});
function calc_length(title)
    {
        return (title
        .join(" ") + " ")
        .replace("- ", " ")
        .replace("+ ", " ")
        .replace("* ", " ")
        .replace("  ", " ")
        .replace("\" ", " ")
        .replace(" \"", " ")
        .length - 1;

    }
function get_all_titles(keywords)
    {
        var result_titles = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i ++)
        {
            var word_count = keywords[i].length;
            var words = keywords[i];
            var previous_count = result_titles.length;
            if (previous_count == 0)
                {
                    previous_count = word_count;
                    for (var sub_ii = 0 ; sub_ii < word_count; sub_ii++)
                    {
                        result_titles[sub_ii] = [];
                        result_titles[sub_ii][i] = words[sub_ii];
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                    for (var sub_i = 0; sub_i < word_count; sub_i++)
                    {
                        for (var sub_ii = 0 ; sub_ii < previous_count; sub_ii++)
                            {
                                if (result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii] == undefined)
                                    {
                                        result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii] = result_titles[sub_ii                                          ].slice();
                                    } 
                                result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii][i] = words[sub_i];
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
        return result_titles;
    }

function substitute(title)
    {
        for (var subs_idx = 0 ; subs_idx < sub_library.length; subs_idx++)
        {
            var index = title.indexOf(sub_library[subs_idx][0]);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                title[index] = sub_library[subs_idx][1];
            }  
        }
        return title;
    }

function shorten_title_length(titles)
    {
        var result = [];
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < titles.length; i++)
            {
                if (calc_length(titles[i]) > max_char_per_title)
                {
                    //substitute with the word in library
                    titles[i] = substitute(titles[i]);
                    // still too long, remove possible words.
                    if (calc_length(titles[i]) > max_char_per_title)
                    {
                        var words = titles[i];
                        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
                        { 
                            if (words[word_idx].indexOf("/") == (words[word_idx].length - 1))
                            {
                                titles[i] = titles[i].splice(word_idx, 1);
                            }

                        }
                        titles[i] = words
                    }
                }
                if (calc_length(titles[i]) <= max_char_per_title)
                    {
                        result[count] = titles[i];
                        count++;
                    }
                else
                {
                    console.log(titles[i].join(" \ "));
                }
            }
            return result;
    }

function change_forward_position(title)
    {
        var words = title;
        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
        {
            if (words[word_idx][words[word_idx].length - 1] == "-")
            {
                if (word_idx != words.length - 1)
                {
                    var tmp = words[word_idx];
                    words[word_idx] = words[word_idx + 1];
                    words[word_idx + 1] = tmp;
                    word_idx ++;
                }
            }
        }
        title = words;
        return title;
    }

function change_backward_position(title)
    {
        var words = title;
        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
        {
            if (words[word_idx][words[word_idx].length - 1] == "+")
            {
                if (word_idx != 0)
                {
                    var tmp = words[word_idx];
                    words[word_idx] = words[word_idx - 1];
                    words[word_idx - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        title = words;
        return title;
    }

function finalize(titles)
    {
        for (var title_idx = 0 ; title_idx < titles.length; title_idx++)
        {
            for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < titles[title_idx].length; word_idx++)
            {
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '+')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '-')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '/')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '"')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '*')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
            }
        }
        return titles;
    }

function generate_title()
    {

        var all_titles = get_all_titles(pTitle);
        //Check keyword files provided by the user, that optional sub words are at least 24
        if (all_titles.length < limit_count)
        {
            alert("not enough different titles");
        }
        //check total char per title
        all_titles = shorten_title_length(all_titles);
        // substitute half randomly.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = substitute(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        //changing position backward.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = change_backward_position(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        //changing position forward.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = change_forward_position(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        all_titles = finalize(all_titles);
        // evaluate.....
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(all_titles[i].join(" \ "));
            console.log(all_titles[i].length);
            alert(pTitle);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your jsFiddle setup: You're using the the `onload` option

> [image: setup]

This wraps your code inside an onload function like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
   /* Your code */
}
```

Because your code is declared within the `onload` function, they are locally scoped within that function. This means they aren't accessible as global objects.

You can change your jsFiddle settings from `onload` to `No wrap - in <head>` and your JavaScript code will just be placed in the `<head>` element of the document and will work fine

Comment: this will allow the user that is entering the title into the prompt box to go through and generate different variations of the user's entered title?

Comment: Yes, You've added that code separately in the `html` section of the jsFiddle. Not sure why you've done that

Comment: I've made the changes and I am still getting the same results that I was before.

Comment: You've got other errors. Do you know how to check your `console`? press F12 and you'll see you've got an error: "pTitle is not defined"

Comment: Try merging your code and using the `onload` setting. Like here https://jsfiddle.net/tdaxs2e6/11/

Comment: My problem now is that it will not repeat in different variations @jasonscript